# Error when I want generate a private key with openssl with symfony

Tags: php, macos, openssl

I have a problem when I want to generate a private key with openssl on MacOS. I want build a API with symfony and I use "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle".

When I run this command :

- `openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa _keygen_bits:4096`

I have this message : `genpkey: Use -help for summary.`

Or normally, I should receive one message who tell me "pass phrase" and after a private key should be generate.

Somebody had a same problem and one solution please because I'm blocked for moment

Thank you for your answers and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm not sure if the command is garbled here (use [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) for best accuracy), but it looks like there's a stray space in `rsa _keygen_bits:4096`.

Comment: Please remove symfony and jwt from your question and your title. The error of the command is not related to those subject and directly with openssl genkey command

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you , actually a space was a problem